Observability in spring boot java application
We have a spring boot application running, having actuator & micrometer-registery-prometheus to expose JVM/application metrics over actuator/prometheus endpoint and we could see the metrics are exposed & consumed by prometheus successfully.
I read if we want to expose application's JMX metrics to prometheus, we have to run the jmx_exporter with the application, so prometheus can scrape JVM related metrics from there.

Do we need jmx_exporter, if we already have micrometer exposing metrics to prometheus ?
Is there some specific jmx metrics/mbeans that micrometer doesn't expose, and we have to use jmx_exporter for this ?



No, 2. No. Those are different mechanisms of exposing metrics, you don't need 1 or the other to get additional metrics.


@M.Deinum. Got it, so micrometer should we able to export everything to prometheus !

JMX would also expose the MicroMeter metrics. Just a different means of transport.


Do we need jmx_exporter, if we already have micrometer exposing metrics to prometheus?

No, Micrometer already collects a lot of metrics through JMX, e.g.: JvmThreadMetrics. If you need something from JMX, you can create a MeterBinder similarly and register a Gauge,FunctionCounter,FunctionTimer, etc.

Is there some specific jmx metrics/mbeans that micrometer doesn't expose, and we have to use jmx_exporter for this ?

If there is something you want please see my previous point and if you also think it would be useful for other users, please open an issue/PR for us and we can consider implementing/merging it in.
